# child() is not a function image upload firebaseSDK Ver9 for Web (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

**What I want to do**

I want to upload images to the ***/images*** directory in the firebase storage.

I'm still having trouble finding an example for Version 9 in the documentation, so if you know of one, please let me know.

**The error that is occurring**

*Uncaught TypeError: storage.child is not a function.*

**Versions**

- FrontEnd: svelte3.0.0
- "rollup": "^2.3.4",
- "rollup-plugin-css-only": "^3.1.0",
- "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^2.0.0",
- "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^7.0.0",
- "rollup-plugin-terser": "^7.0.0",
- firebaseSDK: 9.0.1

**Source Code**

my-firebase.js

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage, ref, list, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage"
...
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "****",
  authDomain: "****",
  projectId: "****",
  storageBucket: "****",
  messagingSenderId: "****",
  appId: "****"
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const storage = getStorage(firebaseApp);
```

api.js

```js
import { doc, getDoc, collection, addDoc, getDocs, updateDoc, deleteDoc, query, where, orderBy, limit } from "firebase/firestore";
import { ref, list, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage"
import { db, storage } from './firebase';

export const postDiary = async(rate = 0, body = '', uid = '', image = null) => {
  try {
    if( image ){
      const uploadRef = ref(storage);
      // ↓ error
      uploadBytes(uploadRef.child('/images/'), image).then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot);
        console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
      });
    }
    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, "diaries"), {
      rate: rate,
      body: body,
      uid: uid,
      createdAt: dayjs().format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss'),
      updatedAt: dayjs().format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss')
    });
...
```

**What I tried**

```js
if( image ){
      const uploadRef = ref(storage).child('/images/');
      // console.log(ref);
      uploadBytes(uploadRef, image).then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot);
        console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
      });
    }
```

```js
if( image ){
      const uploadRef = ref(storage.child('/images/'));
      // console.log(ref);
      uploadBytes(uploadRef, image).then(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot);
        console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `storage.child(...)` construct is from Firebase SDK 8 and earlier. You can't go mixing and matching that with the new modular/functional syntax of v9.

The equivalent in the new syntax is:

```
uploadBytes(ref(uploadRef, '/images/'), image).then(function(snapshot) {
  ...
```

For cases like this, I recommend keeping the reference documentation handy. In this case you'll want to look at the [`ref` function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.md#ref).

Comment: Worked fine.
I overlooked the ref documentation. Thanks for that.

Comment: Oh, I constantly forget some calls, which is how I got pretty good at parsing the error message and finding the docs quickly. ;-)